# How to initialize a CLLocationCoordinate2D struct

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-location

I'm trying to initialize a CLLocationCoordinate2D from a Swift Playground, and I'm getting the error:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
> The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is what I tried:

```
var temporaryCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
```

Comment: It's quite unlikely that this is causing the crash. This code is fine.

Comment: Let me guess you are trying it on a playground

Comment: Yes, I'm working on this in playground.

Answer (score 2):

You have found a very unusual and interesting bug.  I can reproduce your problem by running the following code in a Blank iOS playground:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

var temporaryCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
```

What is going wrong is that the runtime environment, the Playground, is itself crashing.  In the Mac, in the Console app, with Crash Reports left tab, we can see that the Xcode Playground is crashing.

```
Process:               scratch-playground [1696]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices/D22341D9-BFF3-4575-9801-1405F0AA2EA2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/67A50F6D-18E8-4220-A2EB-8673018601AA/scratch-playground-1381-1.app/scratch-playground
Identifier:            scratch-playground
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1697]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [635]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-04-06 21:43:05.608 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 11.2.3 (20D91)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        BFEAE183-A757-B843-D9D2-BF254A4665C2


Time Awake Since Boot: 6300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

External Modification Warnings:
Debugger attached to process.

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1c9d3f588'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (D22341D9-BFF3-4575-9801-1405F0AA2EA2) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPad Pro (9.7-inch)

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803f61fc __exceptionPreprocess + 236
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018016a438 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804053bc __CFExceptionProem + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803fa45c ___forwarding___ + 1408
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803fc42c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   libswiftCoreLocation.dylib          0x00000001b1f98044 $s12CoreLocation39CLLocationCoordinate2DInNSValueObjCType33_25AD2332B1DC67E23B54508C4A7DAD45LLSPys4Int8VGvpfiAFyXEfU_ + 104
6   libswiftCoreLocation.dylib          0x00000001b1f97fcc globalinit_33_25AD2332B1DC67E23B54508C4A7DAD45_func0 + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000180100c48 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000180102300 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
9   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000018eed4ee8 swift_once + 44
10  libswiftCoreLocation.dylib          0x00000001b1f9817c $sSo22CLLocationCoordinate2DVs21_ObjectiveCBridgeable12CoreLocationsACP09_bridgeToC1C01_C5CTypeQzyFTW + 116
11  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000018eeac510 _ZL37bridgeAnythingNonVerbatimToObjectiveCPN5swift11OpaqueValueEPKNS_14TargetMetadataINS_9InProcessEEEb + 360
12  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000018ec10d70 $ss27_bridgeAnythingToObjectiveCyyXlxlF + 184
13  PlaygroundLogger                    0x0000000100c6f9f8 globalinit_33_86996C1BC443F28F24E6A34F24210E4B_func8 + 2132
14  PlaygroundLogger                    0x0000000100c6c848 globalinit_33_B1F54B50FE3698781248948D54A93147_func6 + 520
15  PlaygroundLogger                    0x0000000100c6db44 playground_log_hidden + 276
16  ???                                 0x0000000100c34350 0x0 + 4307764048
17  scratch-playground                  0x0000000100ac2ea4 main + 0
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180365254 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803644ec __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 404
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018035eda8 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018035e58c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018b9c2740 GSEventRunModal + 160
23  UIKitCore                           0x00000001843ccbf0 -[UIApplication _run] + 964
24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001843d19d0 UIApplicationMain + 112
25  scratch-playground                  0x0000000100ac2f7c main + 216
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000180223cbc start + 4

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd7c3c10 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001bd7fc034 pthread_kill + 260
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001800f378c abort + 100
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018021cf20 abort_message + 128
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018020ef1c demangling_terminate_handler() + 296
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018016a6e8 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018021c3c0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018021c358 std::terminate() + 44
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180100c5c _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180102300 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
10  libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018eed4ee8 swift_once + 44
11  libswiftCoreLocation.dylib      0x00000001b1f9817c protocol witness for _ObjectiveCBridgeable._bridgeToObjectiveC() in conformance CLLocationCoordinate2D + 116
12  libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018eeac510 bridgeAnythingNonVerbatimToObjectiveC(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, bool) + 360
13  libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018ec10d70 _bridgeAnythingToObjectiveC<A>(_:) + 184
14  com.apple.dt.PlaygroundLogger   0x0000000100c6f9f8 0x100c68000 + 31224
15  com.apple.dt.PlaygroundLogger   0x0000000100c6c848 0x100c68000 + 18504
16  com.apple.dt.PlaygroundLogger   0x0000000100c6db44 playground_log_hidden + 276
17  ???                             0x0000000100c34350 0 + 4307764048
18  com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.scratch-playground-10BCB7AC-7E28-4D75-BC98-3FA7A44E2F36  0x0000000100ac2ea4 linkResources + 328
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000180365254 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001803644ec __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 404
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000018035eda8 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000018035e58c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
23  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x000000018b9c2740 GSEventRunModal + 160
24  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x00000001843ccbf0 -[UIApplication _run] + 964
25  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x00000001843d19d0 UIApplicationMain + 112
26  com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.scratch-playground-10BCB7AC-7E28-4D75-BC98-3FA7A44E2F36  0x0000000100ac2f7c main + 216
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180223cbc start + 4
```

I think the problem is that there are two Core Location binaries in play:

```
0x18321e000 -        0x1832a8fff  com.apple.corelocation (2420.12.16 - 2420.12.16) <F94D1F57-86D5-3A82-8F2B-80A9AEAC0308> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
```

and

```
0x1b1f96000 -        0x1b1f98fff +libswiftCoreLocation.dylib (5) <EE615605-C11D-3F60-B611-8B1C1D45FEEA> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
```

and the playground is communicating from one world to the other world; talking to the iOS simulator.  But there is an incompatibility between the two as the message is not carried across correctly due to type confusion.  This leads to the

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSValue
> valueWithMKCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
> 0x1c9d3f588' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I think you should file a bug with Apple.  To avoid the problem, write your code based on the iOS Simulator directly, instead of using the Playground.  In such circumstances, your code will execute correctly (since it directly will run against the simulator without the intervening bridge from the Playground).

Comment: It's not unusual and interesting. It's a well-known bug.

Answer (score -1):

As Alexander says in his comment, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted. The cause of the crash is elsewhere.